# Почему "такой-сякой"?))

Tags: этимология

Вдумался в слово (или словосочетание?) "такой-сякой". Интересно, это просто игра слов или есть слово "сякой"? Но почему тогда "такой-сякой" носит негативный характер?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

[Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_old/9260) (оригинальная орфография, 1896—1912.):

> Такой-сякой (бранно, или — вмѣсто произнесенія бранныхъ словъ).
>   Ср. Драть тебя мало, такой-сякой, разоритель, воръ ты безсовѣстный!...
>   Гл. Успенскій. Изъ деревенскаго дневника. Міроѣды.
>   Ср. Ахъ, ты сякой-такой сынъ!... сказалъ Тарасъ Бульба (сыну)... За обиду не посмотрю и не уважу никого.
>   Гоголь. Тарасъ Бульба. 1.
>   Ср. Ты такая и этакая, только хлѣбъ перебиваешь.
>   Гоголь. Женитьба. 1, 3. Сваха.

То есть первоначально это эвфемизм.

Answer (score 0):

*"Сякой"* - слово есть. Производное от *"сей", "сяк"*, то есть "тот"/"этот". Всовреенноязыке почти не используется за пределами выражений *"такой-сякой-(немазанный)", "и такой, и сякой"*  и подобных.